# No Auto Complete Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Im using MS visual studio 2010 PRoofessional version , and in both languages I'm using (C++ and UnrealScript with Nfringe ) there seems to be no auto complete , also with the nfringe there is no auto indentation either .

I was wondering how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you accidentally switched into low-impact IntelliSense mode by pressing

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to go back to the IntelliSense mode.

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing a totally unmanaged C++ dll?  There is no intellisense support for CLI/C++ projects in VS 2010

Answer (score 1):

I have actually problems with C++ and Intellisense since VC6... 
We now use Whole Tomatoes "Visual Assist" and it repairs Intellisense. :-) This single feature is the money worth.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the solution file, do you get a warning about being unable to open the IntelliSense database?  If so, that's the reason—UnrealEngine intentionally has a directory with the same name as the IntelliSense database to prevent its creation (Visual Studio can't create a file if a directory of the same name already exists).  The engine code base is so large that having IntelliSense enabled slows everything to a crawl when you're editing code.

Comment: No I dont get any warnins , the DVD im watching EAt 3d the guy uses the ms visual studio with nfringe and auto complete and inteli sence work fine for him

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Unreal Engine, and I met the same problem before, the solution was set the dirs by myself in VS project setting.

Open the property window of ur game project(e.g UDKGame), navigate to "NMake", "Include Search Path", and fill the needed header search path there.

You may copy the path list from the output of UnrealBuildTool.

The values u set here is only used by Visual Studio's IntelliSense, so there's no need to worry about build error.

This only works for C++, I'm not sure what's wrong with Unreal Script. I just updated to Visual Studio 2010 and has not installed the new nFringe.

Hope this answer is not too late